# Get DatabaseContext instance inside IConfigureOptions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I've followed [this tutorial](https://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions/) to get the options from the database but I am having an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.'

I don't know why it happens. The error is generated within the **`OnModelCreating()`** method, particularly in the **`base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`**. **I use Identity and .NET Core 3**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(x =>
     x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    
    // some code here
    
    serviceCollection.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
        .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
        .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>, ConfigureIdentityOptions>();
}

public class ConfigureIdentityOptions : IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ConfigureIdentityOptions(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public void Configure(IdentityOptions identityOptions)
    {
        using (var currentScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            using (var databaseContext = currentScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>())
            {
                var users = databaseContext.Users.ToList(); // ERROR HERE
            }
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // ERROR HERE

    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Sample.API");
}
```

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/avechuche/.net-core-3-sample.api/src/master/) you can see the whole code.

**Error screenshot**

[image]

Comment: is this caused by a circular dependency, isn't IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions> required by your context.

Comment: @johnny5 Thx! Do I have any way to fix it and be able to load the options from the database? Thank you!

Comment: Either 1. Don't store the configuration in the DB. Or 2. Create a raw sql query to obtain the information. Or 3. Create a dummy context which takes in no configuration, and its sole purpose is to obtain configuration in the start up class only.

Comment: For the second option from johnny 5, you need to try `SqlConnection` to create raw sql query, you could not run the raw sql from `DatabaseContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How strange that there is no "more elegant" solution, perhaps it is a limitation or a bug.